# Tag synonym "301-redirect" -> "redirect"

Tags: support, tags, moderation

I was just going through the various "rewrite" and "redirect" tag variations to get them in order and found that it is not possible to suggest a tag synonym for [301-redirect](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/301-redirect) to [redirect](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redirect).

StackExchange falsely recognizes "301-redirect" as version specific synonym:

> [image]

Could a moderator take care of that? I hope you agree that there's no value in specific "301" or "302" redirect tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your back:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/tags/redirect/synonyms